# Highlighting/Bolding Tcircle elements

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

So I am using `PSTricks` `PSTree` package to build a tree using TCircle ... now I want to bold out some branches by making the lines of the circle and the connecting lines thicker ... can I do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\def\thickline#1#2{\ncline[linewidth=3pt]{#1}{#2}}
\newpsstyle{thick}{edge=\thickline,linewidth=3pt}
\begin{document}
\pstree{\Toval{root}}{%
  \Tcircle[linewidth=3pt]{A}
  \Tcircle{B}}
\quad
\pstree{\Toval{root}}{%
  \Tcircle[style=thick]{A}
  \Tcircle{B}}

\pstree{\Toval{root}}{%
  \Tcircle{A}
  \Tcircle{B}}
\quad
\pstree[linewidth=3pt]{\Toval{root}}{%
  \Tcircle{A}
  \Tcircle{B}}
\end{document}
```

[image]